# epoll VS select

Tags: select, epoll

I have read a couple of networking books to get some idea of differences between epoll and select but they only covered this concepts slightly. I will be appreciated if you guys can provide me the key differences in details.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032598/caveats-of-select-poll-vs-epoll-reactors-in-twisted

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`select` is the standard Unix facility for doing asynchronous IO. Its programming interface is quirky, and its implementation in most Unixes is mediocre at best. It also imposes a limit on the maximum number of descriptors a process can watch, which is inconvenient in an application. Regarding efficiency, the performance of `select` usually degrades linearly with the number of descriptors.

`epoll` is a huge improvement over `select` in terms of programming interface and efficiency, but is only provided in Linux starting from version 2.6. Other Unixes have their specialised calls, too.

Comment: hmm, both of them should be `synchronous IO`

Answer (score 1):

`select` always delivery descriptors to kernel when calling `select()`.
But `epoll` delivery the descriptor once when calling `epoll_ctl()` and get events by calling `epoll_wait()`.

And loop 0 to max_descriptor for checking events when using `select`.
But loop for event occured descriptors for checking events when using `epoll`.

These makes the difference in performance.

And `select` has a limit of maximum number of descriptors because it use bit array.
But `epoll` don't have a limit because it use structure array.

And `select` exists in most of platforms (windows, linux, unix, bsd)
But `epoll` exists only in linux.
Of course, there exists replacements of `epoll` in other platforms (IOCP in windows, kqueue in bsd, etc..)