# Are there any platforms where using structure copy on an fd_set (for select() or pselect()) causes problems?

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

The [`select()` and `pselect()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pselect.html) system calls modify their arguments (the '`fd_set *`' arguments), so the input value tells the system which file descriptors to check and the return values tell the programmer which file descriptors are currently usable.

If you are going to call them repeatedly for the same set of file descriptors, you need to ensure that you have a fresh copy of the descriptors for each call.  The obvious way to do that is to use a structure copy:

```
fd_set ref_set_rd;
fd_set ref_set_wr;
fd_set ref_set_er;
...
...code to set the reference fd_set_xx values...
...
while (!done)
{
    fd_set act_set_rd = ref_set_rd;
    fd_set act_set_wr = ref_set_wr;
    fd_set act_set_er = ref_set_er;
    int bits_set = select(max_fd, &act_set_rd, &act_set_wr,
                          &act_set_er, &timeout);
    if (bits_set > 0)
    {
        ...process the output values of act_set_xx...
    }
 }
```

(*Edited to remove incorrect `struct fd_set` references - as pointed out by 'R..'.*)

My question:

- Are there any platforms where it is not safe to do a structure copy of the `fd_set` values as shown?

I'm concerned lest there be hidden memory allocation or anything unexpected like that.  (There are macros/functions FD_SET(), FD_CLR(), FD_ZERO() and FD_ISSET() to mask the internals from the application.)

I can see that MacOS X (Darwin) is safe; other BSD-based systems are likely to be safe, therefore.  You can help by documenting other systems that you know are safe in your answers.

(I do have minor concerns about how well the `fd_set` would work with more than 8192 open file descriptors - the default maximum number of open files is only 256, but the maximum number is 'unlimited'.  Also, since the structures are 1 KB, the copying code is not dreadfully efficient, but then running through a list of file descriptors to recreate the input mask on each cycle is not necessarily efficient either.  Maybe you can't do `select()` when you have that many file descriptors open, though that is when you are most likely to need the functionality.)

---

There's a related SO question - asking about ['poll() vs select()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970979/what-are-the-differences-between-poll-and-select) which addresses a different set of issues from this question.

---

*Note that on MacOS X - and presumably BSD more generally - there is an `FD_COPY()` macro or function, with the effective prototype:*

- `extern void FD_COPY(const restrict fd_set *from, restrict fd_set *to);`.

*It might be worth emulating on platforms where it is not already available.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `struct fd_set` is just a regular C structure, that should always be fine.  I personally don't like doing structure copying via the `=` operator, since I've worked on plenty of platforms that didn't have access to the normal set of compiler intrinsics.  Using `memcpy()` explicitly rather than having the compiler insert a function call is a better way to go, in my book.

From the C spec, section **6.5.16.1 Simple assignment** (edited here for brevity):

> One of the following shall hold:
>
> ...
>
> - the left operand has a qualified or unqualified version of a structure or union type compatible with the type of the right;
>
> ...
>
> In *simple assignment* (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.
>
> If the value being stored in an object is read from another object that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall have qualified or unqualified versions of a compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So there you go, as long as `struct fd_set` is a actually a regular C `struct`, you're guaranteed success.  It does depend, however, on your compiler emitting some kind of code to do it, or relying on whatever `memcpy()` intrinsic it uses for structure assignment.  If your platform can't link against the compiler's intrinsic libraries for some reason, it may not work.

You will have to play some tricks if you have more open file descriptors than will fit into `struct fd_set`.  The linux [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_set) says:

> An `fd_set` is a fixed size buffer. Executing `FD_CLR()` or `FD_SET()` with a value of `fd` that is negative or is equal to or larger than `FD_SETSIZE` will result in undefined behavior. Moreover, POSIX requires `fd` to be a valid file descriptor.

As mentioned below, it might not be worth the effort to prove that your code is safe on all systems.  `FD_COPY()` is provided for just such a use, and is, presumably, always guaranteed:

> `FD_COPY(&fdset_orig, &fdset_copy)` replaces an already allocated `&fdset_copy` file descriptor set with a copy of `&fdset_orig`.

Comment: But suppose someone got fancy and stored a pointer to an allocated array for the bits...then copying the structure would copy the pointer and not the pointed at data.  The structure could be copied; all structures can be copied.  But then there'd potential for things going wrong.  I think it is unlikely to be a problem, but I can't see wording in POSIX that rules this out - unless it is that the macro FD_SETSIZE is implied to be a constant and ...

Comment: @Jonathan, that's a good point.  People can make crazy implementation choices sometimes.  I'll edit my answer to mention `FD_COPY`.

Comment: Clearly, someone else had similar issues - so they invented FD_COPY().  Unfortunately, it is not in the POSIX 2008 standard or on many other platforms - including older versions of Linux (kernel 2.6.9; glibc 2.3.4).

Comment: @Jonathan: I explained in my answer why `fd_set`, as long as it's implemented under standard C, could never use allocated memory.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, there is no `struct fd_set`. It's simply called `fd_set`. However, POSIX does require it to be a struct type, so copying is well-defined.

Secondly, there is no way under standard C in which the `fd_set` object could contain dynamically allocated memory, since there is no requirement to use any function/macro to free it before returning. Even if the compiler has `alloca` (a pre-vla extension for stack-based allocation), `fd_set` could not use memory allocated on the stack, because a program might pass a pointer to the `fd_set` to another function which uses `FD_SET`, etc., and the allocated memory would cease to be valid as soon as it returns to the caller. Only if the C compiler offered some extension for destructors could `fd_set` use dynamic allocation.

In conclusion, it seems to be safe just to assign/`memcpy` `fd_set` objects, but to be sure, I would do something like:

```
#ifndef FD_COPY
#define FD_COPY(dest,src) memcpy((dest),(src),sizeof *(dest))
#endif
```

or alternatively just:

```
#ifndef FD_COPY
#define FD_COPY(dest,src) (*(dest)=*(src))
#endif
```

Then you'll use the system's provided `FD_COPY` macro if it exists, and only fall back to the theoretically-potentially-unsafe version if it's missing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake in the question - I will fix that.

Comment: That FD_COPY macro has a problem if you are giving it pointers to fd_sets (which is what the other FD_*() functions take). E.g. in FD_COPY(pFdSet1, pFdSet2), the sizeof(pFdSet1) will typically be 4 since pFdSe3t1 is a pointer to fd_set. Rather than "sizeof(dest)" substitute "sizeof(fd_set)".

Comment: Note that the answer has `dest` as first argument while BSD implementation has `src` as first argument.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that POSIX doesn't guarantee that copying a `fd_set` has to "work".  I'm not personally aware of anywhere that it doesn't, but then I've never done the experiment.

You can use the `poll()` alternative (which is also POSIX).  It works in a very similar way to `select()`, except that the input/output parameter is not opaque (and contains no pointers, so a bare `memcpy` will work), and its design also entirely removes the need to make a copy of the "requested file descriptors" structure (because the "requested events" and "returned events" are stored in different fields).

You are also correct to surmise that `select()` (and `poll()`) don't scale particularly well to large numbers of file descriptors - this is because every time the function returns, you must loop through every file descriptor to test if there was activity on it.  The solutions to this are various non-standard interfaces (eg. Linux's `epoll()`, FreeBSD's `kqueue`), which you may need to look into if you find you are having latency problems.

Answer (score 2):

I've done a little research on MacOS X, Linux, AIX, Solaris and HP-UX, and there are some interesting results.  I used the following program:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#else
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */

#ifdef SET_FD_SETSIZE
#define FD_SETSIZE SET_FD_SETSIZE
#endif

#ifdef USE_SYS_TIME_H
#include <sys/time.h>
#else
#include <sys/select.h>
#endif /* USE_SYS_TIME_H */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("FD_SETSIZE = %d; sizeof(fd_set) = %d\n", (int)FD_SETSIZE, (int)sizeof(fd_set));
    return 0;
}
```

It was compiled twice on each platform:

```
cc -o select select.c
cc -o select -DSET_FD_SETSIZE=16384
```

(And on one platform, HP-UX 11.11, I had to add -DUSE_SYS_TIME_H to get things to compile at all.)  I separately did a visual check on FD_COPY - only MacOS X seemed to include it, and that had to be activated by ensuring that `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` was not defined or by defining `_DARWIN_C_SOURCE`.

#### AIX 5.3

- Default FD_SETSIZE is 65536
- The FD_SETSIZE parameter can be resized
- No FD_COPY

#### HP-UX 11.11

- No `<sys/select.h>` header - use `<sys/time.h>` instead
- Default FD_SETSIZE is 2048
- The FD_SETSIZE parameter can be resized
- No FD_COPY

#### HP-UX 11.23

- Has `<sys/select.h>`
- Default FD_SETSIZE is 2048
- The FD_SETSIZE parameter can be resized
- No FD_COPY

#### Linux (kernel 2.6.9, glibc 2.3.4)

- Default FD_SETSIZE is 1024
- The FD_SETSIZE parameter *cannot* be resized
- No FD_COPY

#### MacOS X 10.6.2

- Default FD_SETSIZE is 1024
- The FD_SETSIZE parameter can be resized
- FD_COPY is defined if strict POSIX compliance is not requested or if `_DARWIN_C_SOURCE` is specified

#### Solaris 10 (SPARC)

- Default FD_SETSIZE is 1024 for 32-bit, 65536 for 64-bit
- The FD_SETSIZE parameter can be resized
- No FD_COPY

Clearly, a trivial modification to the program allows automatic checking of FD_COPY:

```
#ifdef FD_COPY
    printf("FD_COPY is a macro\n");
#endif
```

What is not necessarily trivial is finding out how to ensure that it is available; you end up doing the manual scan and working out how to trigger it.

On all these machines, it looks like an `fd_set` can be copied by a structure copy without running into risk of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to add this as a comment to caf's answer, but there are libraries to abstract over the non-standard interfaces like `epoll()` and `kqueue`. libevent is one, and libev another. I think GLib also has one that ties into its mainloop.