# is there any consequence if I create a lot of pipes in the same program

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I need to create a lot of pipes, I want to use them as fifo queues between threads in the same process, and then do select/poll on them.

my question is, if I create a lot of queues, wiil this have big impact on the performance of the program? like pipe number limitations, resource-consuming, etc

thanks!

Comment: You should look at eventfd.

Answer (score 5):

There is a per-process limit on the number of files you can keep open, and pipes are files, so you consume that limit.

Comment: what is the limit? how big?

Comment: @misteryes: **ulimit -n** will tell you.

Comment: It is often 256 or 1024 by default, and can usually be extended to 32767 before you have to reconfigure the kernel.  Also, each pipe uses two file descriptors, of course.

Answer (score 2):

`select` can only handle file descriptors with values up to `FD_SETSIZE` (1024 is the typical value), so you should definitely use `poll` and forget about `select` if you'll have lots. Note however that the default `ulimit` for open files in a process is typically the same as `FD_SETSIZE`, so you'll also want to increase that if you need more. In addition, pipes are mildly expensive in terms of kernelspace memory usage (at least a page or two for each open pipe, probably more) and performance (sending/receiving data requires multiple copies and transitions between user and kernel space).

As long as you only have one pipe per thread, you'll probably be spending a lot more resources on having the thread around than the pipe, so your design doesn't look so bad. However, if you're using threads, it *could* be a lot more efficient to use your own userspace-only queues based on condition variables. This is much more idiomatic in the POSIX threads scheme of things, but less idiomatic in the way Linux-trained application developers tend to work. It would also make it so there's essentially no limit on the number of queues you can have (except available memory).

If possible, rather than focusing on the cost and limits, I would focus on the interface requirements. Is there a strong *reason* you want to be using `poll` or `select`, e.g. having your threads wait simultaneously on your queues and other file-descriptor-based events? Or are you just leaning towards pipes because it's what you know? In the former case, I think pipes probably make sense, but in the latter case I would spend a little time researching the other options and see which really makes more sense to your problem.

Comment: See [Are there any platforms where using structure copy on an `fd_set` (for `select()` or `pselect()`) causes problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421672/are-there-any-platforms-where-using-structure-copy-on-an-fd-set-for-select-or) for information about changing `FD_SETSIZE`.

Comment: Or just don't try. It's well into the realm of UB and in fact there's presently a discussion on the glibc list about `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` doing bounds checking on the `FD_*` macros...

Comment: Not an option if you need more file descriptors open than FD_SETSIZE allows and you need to select on those descriptors.  There are real programs that have such requirements — not many, but some.

Comment: The option is to use `poll`, not `select`.