# About the socket select() crash

Tags: c, sockets, embedded-linux

**old version**

```
FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_ZERO(&master);
FD_SET(sockserver, &master);
fdmax =  sockserver;

for(;;) {
    rfds = master;
    if( select(fdmax+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("select");
        exit(1);
    }
```

**new version**

```
FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_ZERO(&master);
FD_SET(sockserver, &master);
fdmax =  sockserver;

for(;;) {
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    for(j=0;j<max_socket;j++){
        if(FD_ISSET(j,&master))
            FD_SET(j,&rfds);
    }
    /* Not copying directly, because you can't assume that the set is integer type.
         It may be anything. */
    if( select(fdmax+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("select");
        exit(1);
    }
```

I tried old version and will crash when run to select(), then I searched new version and try, it's still crash. I also tried to move out all local variables that I thought it might be stack overflow, but it still crash.

Can someone answer this problem?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's `max_socket` set to?  Why isn't that `fdmax + 1`?

Comment: This is a long shot, but check that sockserver is less than FD_SETSIZE.

Comment: Also, on BSD at least, there is `void FD_COPY(fd_set *fdset_orig, fd_set *fdset_copy);` — with cack-handed '(src, dst)' arguments instead of '(dst, src)' like most other copy functions (`strcpy()`, `memmove()`, etc).  Unfortunately, POSIX doesn't standardize it (see [`FD_CLR()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/FD_CLR.html)); I wonder if that's because of divergent implementations.  Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS checked) doesn't seem to have `FD_COPY`.

Comment: You might also notice that POSIX [`<sys/select.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_select.h.html) says: _The `<sys/select.h>` header shall define the `fd_set` type as a structure._  There's at least a moderate chance you can use structure copy, unless you're tinkering with its size — see [Are there any platforms where using structure copy on an `fd_set` causes problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421672) and my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2436796/15168) there.  (Maybe that needs an update 5 years later?)

Comment: regarding this line: 'rfds = master;' both of these items are structs that contain several fields.  so a simple assignment will not work.  Suggest using memcpy(&rfds, &master, sizeof( rfds ) );

Answer (score 2):

On both versions, you are not setting `fdmax` correctly.  If any sockets in the `master` are greater than the value of `sockserver`, `select()` will ignore them.  The first parameter of `select()` must be +1 higher than the largest socket in `rfds`.

Also, in the *old* version, there is no guarantee that `rfds = master` is a valid operation. On platforms where it is potentially wrong, use `FD_COPY()` instead:

```
FD_COPY(&master, &rfds);
```

But in this case, by using the *new* version, you do not need to use `FD_COPY()` (if it is available).

And as Craig stated in comments, make sure `max_socket` is actually valid, does not exceeding `FD_SETSIZE`, etc.

Try this:

```
FD_ZERO(&master);
FD_SET(sockserver, &master);
...    

FD_ZERO(&rfds);
fdmax = -1;
for(j = 0; (j < max_socket) && (j < FD_SETSIZE); ++j){
    if (FD_ISSET(j, &master)) {
        FD_SET(j, &rfds);
        fdmax = j;
    }
}
if (select(fdmax+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
    perror("select");
    exit(1);
}
...
```

If you are still having problems, then you need to provide a more realistic [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem in action.