# New to pipe() and fork() in C++ -

Tags: c++, fork, pipe

**Environment:** Linux 2.6.32 (RHEL 6.3) on x86_64 with gcc 4.4.6

**Background:** I am running doing some heavy data crunching: ~500 GB input data spread over ~2000 files. My main process forks N children, each of which receives a list of filenames to crunch.

**What I want** is for console I/O to pass through the parent. I have been looking into `pipe()` and see some fascinating stuff about using `poll()` to have my parent block until there are error messages to read. It seems that I need to have N pipes (one per child) and pass `poll()` information about what signals I want to listen to. Also, I *think* that once I `dup2(pipe[1], STDOUT)` in each child, each child should be able to write to the pipe with `cout << stuff;` as usual, right?

**First**, is what I have said above about multiple pipes, `poll()`ing and `dup2()` correct?

**Second**, how do I set up the parent `poll()` loop so that I move on once all the children have died?

Right now, this (incomplete) section of code reads as follows:

```
int status;
while (1) { // wait for stuff
    while ((status = poll(pollfds, ss.max_forks, -1)) > 1)
        cout << "fork "<< status << ": " << pipes[status][0];
    if (status == -1)   Die(errno, "poll error");
    if (status == 0) { // check that we still have at least one open fd
        bool still_running = false;
        for (int i=0; i<ss.max_forks; i++) {
             // check pipe i and set still_running if it is not zero
        }
        if (!still_running)
            break;
    }
}
```

**Third**, what should I set and when should I set it with fcntl()? Do I want to do O_ASYNC? Do I want to do blocking or nonblocking?

Comment: How many children do you expect? Maybe you're better off with a single fifo or domain socket for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you need to close() the respective "unused" side in both processes (parent and child), to make sure the "broken pipe" comes across. Thus, if the child writes into Pipe[0], then the parent will read from Pipe[1] and close its own Pipe[0]. Likewise, the child will close Pipe[1].

If you do this, the parent will get an error when it reads from the pipe after the child has died. Don't forget to use one of the waitpid()-style functions to clean up the dead processes.

You might want to sett the handles to nonblocking, so you can just read whatever is there without having to use 1-byte-reads which would be horribly inefficient. Although I just make one call to read() with a suitable buffersize (usually 1024 or 4096), and just let the next poll trigger if there's more data. But then, I usually just have one child to work with, not a few hundred :-)

As for your loop, you'll have to track the state of each child, and exit when you have no live children left.

EDIT: actually, I find that I assume the child is dead when I get a 0-byte read even though POLLIN was set, or when I get POLLERR or POLLHUP flags. Not sure which case is the correct one...

Comment: The `read(2)` function will return 0. It is not exactly an error condition, it is _end of file_.

Comment: Yeah, I was considering adding that as a "feeling", since that's what I was looking for on similar setups using select(). Except that select() doesn't have "HUP", which felt like a strong candidate too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a question about `select()` vs `poll()`: [What are the differences between poll and select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970979/what-are-the-differences-between-poll-and-select)

However, have you thought about using threads as opposed to separate processes? You have more control over the interactions with threads, and the communications are through data structures rather than pipelined I/O streams. Pipelines are *expensive*; you're going through the OS, and you have to format the results for output / parse the results on input, also expensive.

One last point: Whether you are using lightweight threads or heavyweight fork/exec, you do not want to launch 2000 of them at once unless you have a 2000 CPU multiprocessor. You will create a situation with very expensive and continuous context swapping if you have more threads/processes in contention for CPU than you have CPUs.