# posix_spawnp and piping child output to a string

Tags: c++, c, posix, ipc

I am struggling with process creation and piping the child process' output into a string of the parent process. I got it working on Windows (using CreatePipe and CreateProcess and ReadFile), but can't seem to get the exact analog on Unix to work. This is my code:

```
#include <spawn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int exit_code;
  int cout_pipe[2];
  int cerr_pipe[2];
  posix_spawn_file_actions_t action;

  if(pipe(cout_pipe) || pipe(cerr_pipe))
    cout << "pipe returned an error.\n";

  posix_spawn_file_actions_init(&action);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&action, cout_pipe[0]);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&action, cerr_pipe[0]);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&action, cout_pipe[1], 1);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&action, cerr_pipe[1], 2);

  posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&action, cout_pipe[1]);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&action, cerr_pipe[1]);

  vector<string> argmem = {"bla"};
  vector<char*> args = {&argmem[0][0], nullptr}; // I don't want to call new.

  pid_t pid;
  if(posix_spawnp(&pid, "echo", &action, NULL, &args[0], NULL) != 0)
    cout << "posix_spawnp failed with error: " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
  //close(cout_pipe[0]);
  //close(cerr_pipe[0]);

  close(cout_pipe[1]);
  close(cerr_pipe[1]);

  waitpid(pid,&exit_code,0);
  cout << "exit code: " << exit_code << "\n";

  // Read from pipes
  const size_t buffer_size = 1024;
  string buffer;
  buffer.resize(buffer_size);
  ssize_t bytes_read = read(cout_pipe[0], &buffer[0], buffer_size);
  while ((bytes_read = read(cout_pipe[0], &buffer[0], buffer_size)) > 0)
  {
    cout << "read " << bytes_read << " bytes from stdout.\n";
    cout << buffer.substr(0, static_cast<size_t>(bytes_read)+1) << "\n";
    bytes_read = read(cout_pipe[0], &buffer[0], buffer_size);
  }
  if(bytes_read == -1)
    cout << "Failure reading from stdout pipe.\n";
  while ((bytes_read = read(cerr_pipe[0], &buffer[0], buffer_size)) > 0)
  {
    cout << "read " << bytes_read << " bytes from stderr.\n";
    cout << buffer.substr(0, static_cast<size_t>(bytes_read)+1) << "\n";
    bytes_read = read(cout_pipe[0], &buffer[0], buffer_size);
  }
  if(bytes_read == -1)
    cout << "Failure reading from stderr pipe.\n";

  posix_spawn_file_actions_destroy(&action);
}
```

The output is:

> exit code: 0

So I suppose everything is working except the actual piping. What is wrong here? I also wonder if there is a way to read the piped bytes in a waitpid loop, but when I try that, the parent process hangs infinitely.

Comment: I had never heard of `posix_spawnp`. What's wrong with good old `popen`? What an interesting syscall/library function it is. Will remember this :)

Comment: `popen` doesn't have the required flexibility: AFAICT I can't redirect stderr with that. It is also the function that most closely resembles the `CreateProcess` API. Heck, MSDN even has `_spawnvp` which resembles `posix_spawnp`, but as I said, my `CreateProcess` code is basically working fine. It's the Unix side that's currently not cooperating :(

Comment: I added the C tag to raise interest. Although the code is technically C++, the important bits (ie the piping and spawning) is pure C.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`posix_spawn` is interesting and useful, which makes this question worth necromancing -- even if it is no longer relevant to the OP.

There are some significant bugs in the code as posted.  I suspect that some of these were the result of hacking in desperation, but I don't know which was the original bug:

1. The `args` array does not include the `argv[0]` that would represent the executable name.  This results in the `echo` program never seeing the intended `argv[1]` ("bla").
2. The `read()` function is called from different places in a way that just doesn't make sense.  A correct way to do this would be to only call `read` as part of the control expression for the `while` loops.
3. `waitpid()` is called before reading from the pipes.  This prevents the I/O from completing (in non-trivial cases at least).
4. A more subtle issue with this code is that attempts to read all of the child's `stdout` before reading anything from `stderr`.  In principle, this could cause the child to block while attempting to write to `stderr`, thus preventing the program from completing.  Creating an efficient solution to this is more complicated as it requires that you can read from whichever pipe has available data.  I used [`poll()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970979/what-are-the-differences-between-poll-and-select) for this.  Another approach would be to use multiple threads.

Additionally, I have used `sh` (the command shell, i.e. `bash`) as the child process.  This provides a great deal of additional flexibility, such as running a pipeline instead of a single executable.  In particular, though, using `sh` provides the simple convenience of not having to manage the parsing of the command-line.

```
/*BINFMTCXX: -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror
*/

#include <spawn.h> // see manpages-posix-dev
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int exit_code;
  int cout_pipe[2];
  int cerr_pipe[2];
  posix_spawn_file_actions_t action;

  if(pipe(cout_pipe) || pipe(cerr_pipe))
    cout << "pipe returned an error.\n";

  posix_spawn_file_actions_init(&action);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&action, cout_pipe[0]);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&action, cerr_pipe[0]);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&action, cout_pipe[1], 1);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&action, cerr_pipe[1], 2);

  posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&action, cout_pipe[1]);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&action, cerr_pipe[1]);

//string command = "echo bla"; // example #1
  string command = "pgmcrater -width 64 -height 9 |pgmtopbm |pnmtoplainpnm";
  string argsmem[] = {"sh","-c"}; // allows non-const access to literals
  char * args[] = {&argsmem[0][0],&argsmem[1][0],&command[0],nullptr};

  pid_t pid;
  if(posix_spawnp(&pid, args[0], &action, NULL, &args[0], NULL) != 0)
    cout << "posix_spawnp failed with error: " << strerror(errno) << "\n";

  close(cout_pipe[1]), close(cerr_pipe[1]); // close child-side of pipes

  // Read from pipes
  string buffer(1024,' ');
  std::vector<pollfd> plist = { {cout_pipe[0],POLLIN}, {cerr_pipe[0],POLLIN} };
  for ( int rval; (rval=poll(&plist[0],plist.size(),/*timeout*/-1))>0; ) {
    if ( plist[0].revents&POLLIN) {
      int bytes_read = read(cout_pipe[0], &buffer[0], buffer.length());
      cout << "read " << bytes_read << " bytes from stdout.\n";
      cout << buffer.substr(0, static_cast<size_t>(bytes_read)) << "\n";
    }
    else if ( plist[1].revents&POLLIN ) {
      int bytes_read = read(cerr_pipe[0], &buffer[0], buffer.length());
      cout << "read " << bytes_read << " bytes from stderr.\n";
      cout << buffer.substr(0, static_cast<size_t>(bytes_read)) << "\n";
    }
    else break; // nothing left to read
  }

  waitpid(pid,&exit_code,0);
  cout << "exit code: " << exit_code << "\n";

  posix_spawn_file_actions_destroy(&action);
}
```

Comment: I didn't thoroughly button this up.  There's plenty of room for better error checking and resource cleanup.

Comment: Why didn't you pass in just args but did &args[0] to posix_spawn()'s 5th argument?

Comment: @Dula: The form I used is more general and more clear to me.  It works for pointers, but also for class-based array managers such as `std::vector` and `std::string`.  I use that form in several places, including `&buffer[0]`, which would not have worked as just `buffer`.

Comment: here is a snippet that instead of poll() uses select(), https://github.com/pixley/InvestigativeProgramming/blob/114b698339fb0243f50cf5bfbe5d5a701733a125/test_spawn_pipe.cpp