# select() on TCP socket works only the first loop

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, select, tcp

```
void async_socket_rcv(int clientfd);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Configure buffer to output immediately
    setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0);

    //Mysql version
    printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

    //Initialize the FDs for the sockets
    int socketfd, clientfd;

    //Initialize the list of FDs to monitor for input
    fd_set fd_monitor;
    int select_res;
    FD_ZERO(&fd_monitor);

    struct timeval select_timeout;
    select_timeout.tv_sec = 3;
    select_timeout.tv_usec = 0;


    //Initialize the thread id
    pthread_t thread;

    ...

    //Create the listen socket
    socketfd = create_inet_server_socket("0.0.0.0", "5671", LIBSOCKET_TCP, LIBSOCKET_IPv4, 0);

    if(socketfd < 0){
        printf("Error creating listen socket!");
        return -1;
    }else{
        printf("Listening...");
    }

    FD_SET(socketfd, &fd_monitor);
    //FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fd_monitor);

    while(1)
    {
        select_res = select(sizeof(fd_monitor) * 8, &fd_monitor, NULL, NULL, &select_timeout);

        if(FD_ISSET(socketfd, &fd_monitor))
        {
            clientfd = accept_inet_stream_socket(socketfd,0,0,0,0,0,0);
            pthread_create(&thread, NULL, async_socket_rcv, clientfd);
        }
        select_timeout.tv_sec = 3;
        select_timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Hello all

I am trying to use the `select()` function to call a function when a client connects without having to block on the `accept()` function. I need to be able to accept `stdin` without interrupting the server.

My code above works, but only once. When I step through the code, i can see that `select_res` is 1 *only* if I connect to the server within the *first* iteration of `select()`. After that, nothing happens.

I'm sure one of you will spot some small error on my part, but for the life of me I can't see what I did wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select` alters the passed in `fd_set`s, setting the descriptors that have activity and unsetting those that don't. Since you don't reset `fd_monitor` in your loop, you used the altered `fd_set`.

Move the `FD_ZERO` and `FD_SET` calls to the beginning of the loop.

Comment: Thank you sir! I must have read it 20 times... "On return, each of the input sets is modified to indicate the subset of descriptions that are ready." Sorry it didn't make it to the old melon :)

Answer (score 0):

While the answer above is 100% correct, it actually illustrates why using select() now smeels like 18th century. There is a wonderful poll(), which when used, would save you from all your troubles!

Comment: I can't remember where, but i seem to remember reading that poll was more costly than select. True? This server will be running on a raspberry pi

Comment: I have never heard of poll being costlier than select. There is that quirk that select allows to specify timeouts in nanoseconds (through timeval), but poll only gives you miliseconds. But this is not the delay, this is maximum wait timeout. Other than that, I am not aware of any benefits of select over poll.

Comment: Are you aware of any benefits, other than simplicity, of poll over select?

Comment: @MatthewGoulart From what I've gathered, `select` is an older interface and didn't scale as well, which led to the creation of `poll`. See also [What are the differences between poll and select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970979/what-are-the-differences-between-poll-and-select)

Comment: @MatthewGoulart, your whole question clearly indicates one of them :) Since poll() returns affected descriptors separately from subscribed, you do not need to re-init them, and the problem above simply would not happen! Imagine hours saved on debugging.

Comment: True. Although I do like the readability of select(). Now that I know how it works it's easy to follow the code. I'll stick with select but keep poll in mind for future projects. Thanks!