# Is select on Windows similar to epoll?

Tags: c++, sockets, select, epoll

I have tested the function `select()` on Windows, and found that the param `fd_set` which is used in `select()` outputed with the satisfying sockets. So does `select()` on Windows play a similar role as `epoll()` on Linux?

How I tested it is by debugging, finding that the front elements is changed by system and all of them are the satisfying ones.

Comment: *"How I tested it is by debuging,"* - it might be more useful to read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select) instead of figuring out what it does by debugging. Apart from that select on Windows matches the functionality of select on Linux (and other UNIX systems or systems supporting Berkeley sockets). epoll provides similar functionality, but more efficient - see [select vs epoll](https://www.google.com/search?q=select+vs+epoll) for more.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between poll and select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970979/what-are-the-differences-between-poll-and-select)